# amp-list [src] expression evaluates but doesn't fire network request

Tags: amp-html

I'm still getting used to AMP and expressions so apologies if this seems like a basic qn!

I need to use a slightly different URL for `<amp-list [src]>` based on whether a state is set or not.

- if state selectedStation.selectedStation is an empty string, call deals.json?country=AMP_GEO(ISOCountry)
- else, call deals.json?country=AMP_GEO(ISOCountry)&origin=AMP_STATE(selectedStation.selectedStation)

Initial state:

```
<amp-state id="selectedStation">
    <script type="application/json">
        {
            "selectedStation": ""
        }
    </script>
</amp-state>
```

amp-list expression:

```
<amp-list class="mt1" width="auto" height="150px" layout="fixed-height" 
  [src]="selectedStation.selectedStation == '' ? 'deals.json? 
  country=AMP_GEO(ISOCountry)' : 'deals.json? country=AMP_GEO(ISOCountry)&origin=AMP_STATE(selectedStation.selectedStation)'">
```

The expression evaluates as seen from the console log warning using #development=1 mode:
*Default value (null) does not match first result (deals.json?country=AMP_GEO(ISOCountry)) for . We recommend writing expressions with matching default values, but this can be safely ignored if intentional.*

However, the request isn't fired. Am I doing something wrong with my expression or missing anything obvious?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: height="150px" should change to height="150". Is it working?

Comment: unfortunately not, it doesn't seem related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [amp-bind](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind#a-simple-example) documentation (emphasis mine):

> For performance and to avoid the risk of unexpected content jumping, `amp-bind` **does not evaluate expressions on page load**. This means that the visual elements should be given a default state and not rely `amp-bind` for initial render.

In other words, since you only specified `[src]` and no `src`, `src` is empty on page load and `[src]` will only evaluate when the user interacts with the page. You'll probably want to have both of them set:

```
<amp-list
  class="mt1"
  width="auto"
  height="150px"
  layout="fixed-height"
  src="deals.json?country=AMP_GEO(ISOCountry)"
  [src]="selectedStation.selectedStation == '' ? 'deals.json?country=AMP_GEO(ISOCountry)' : 'deals.json? country=AMP_GEO(ISOCountry)&origin=AMP_STATE(selectedStation.selectedStation)'"
>
```